# Trim the first character from a string variable

Tags: string, robotframework

I get a list from a website but it pulls an html tag (same first character as the role I am trying to get) along with the role. For example, I need to get the role of this user, and the role is "DeveloperContributor" but the list returns "CDeveloperContributor". I am curious to know if you can string slice like   ${string}[1:]

I've debated 'Split String To Characters' and then iterating through the list and concatenating each letter individually to a ${endString} var (skipping first entry of the list ofc), but that's clumsy and I'm hoping there's a cleaner/simpler solution out there than this...

```
@{cutFirstLetter}=  Split String To Characters  ${TABLE}[0]
${lenOfListStringOfChar}=  Get Length  ${cutFirstLetter}
${endString}=  ${EMPTY}
:FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  1   ${lenOfListStringOfChar}
\  ${temp}=  ${cutFirstLetter}[${i}]
\  ${endString}=  Catenate  ${endString}  ${temp}
```

Assume ${TABLE} is just a list of strings. The output of that above code works, but it's clunky. I am trying to compare it to a list of the list of valid positions, so I get (not running that above code)
Ex: 'DeveloperContributor != CDeveloperContributor'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Get Substring](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Substring) from the String library:

```
${endString}=    Get Substring    ${TABLE}[0]    1
```

Alternatively, plain old python string slice, through `Evaluate`:

```
${endString}=    Evaluate    """${TABLE}[0]"""[1:]
```